# Error with tomcat when deploying Google App Engine application

Tags: google-app-engine, tomcat, servlets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/springboot-helloworld) to deploy my API on GAE with a SQL Cloud DB and it's been several hours now that I'm testing all the possibilities but I still encounter several errors that I can't fix. When I exclude the tomcat dependency I get the error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletMapping
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:206) ~[spring-test-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) [spring-test-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7
```

When I remove this exclusion from my pom.xml :

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

the app works fine locally and connect well to my SQL Cloud DB but when I deploy with flex env I get those error on myproject.region.r.appspot.com :

```
Error: Server Error
   The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
   Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

and in cloud console Error reporting :

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
at
org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart (ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:330)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1406)
at
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp (AppEngineWebAppContext.java:175)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1368)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:778)
```

Thank you.

Comment: It seems the error came from the failed connection between App Engine and Cloud SQL. There are so many reason for 502 error like wrong dependencies, wrong configuration and etc. Please include in your question how do you connect both, for us to help you.

Comment: The problem was solved by starting from scratch with a more recent tutorial. The first one used servlets and was deployed via a .war whereas here we use a .jar.
Thank you for trying to help me.